# How to touch multiple files using range in terminal

Tags: shell, terminal, zsh

I use zsh. I want to touch 0023.rb 0024.rb .... 0040.rb.

Is there better way to touch files using range in terminal?

```
# something like this
$touch (0023..0040).rb
```

Comment: This is a question about shell scripting.  Closing seems overzealous.

Answer (score 3):

tested under zsh:

```
kent$  touch {0010..0015}.foo

kent$  l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent 0 May 15 16:20 0010.foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent 0 May 15 16:20 0011.foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent 0 May 15 16:20 0012.foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent 0 May 15 16:20 0013.foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent 0 May 15 16:20 0014.foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent 0 May 15 16:20 0015.foo
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to [use `seq` to generate a series of numbers](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-generating-print-range-sequence-of-numbers.html), then pipe the output of that to [`xargs`](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-xargs-construct-argument-lists-utility/):

```
 seq 23 42|xargs -Inumber touch 00number.rb
```

You can format the numbers using [standard printf format specifier](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).  For minimum-4-digit, 0-padded number, use `%04.f`:

```
 seq -f %04.f 99 101|xargs -Inumber touch number.rb
```